# how to set and get value of jquery buttons

Tags: jquery

I have many Yes and No radio button to set inside an Edit form, I want to set values returned from an ajax query. and after editing the new value in radio button, need to save it in database. I tried this :

```
<div class="span2">
    <div class="control-group checkForError">
        <label class="control-label" for="power">Power On OK?
        </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="radio" >
                     <input type="radio" name="power" id="pyes" value="YES" />Yes
                 </label>
                 <label class="radio" >
                     <input type="radio" name="power" id="pno" value="NO" />No
                 </label>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span2">
    <div class="control-group checkForError">
        <label class="control-label" for="boot">System Boot OK?
        </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="radio" >
                    <input type="radio" name="boot" id="boyes" value="YES"/>Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio" >
                    <input type="radio" name="boot" id="bono" value="NO" />No
                </label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here i try to set values what i got from db using passValues()

```
function passValues(){

    var power_value="YES";
    var boot_value="NO";

    if(power_value=="YES"){ $("#pyes").parent().addClass("checked"); }
    else{ $("#pno").parent().addClass("checked"); }
    $("#power").trigger('change');

    if(boot_value=="YES"){ $("#cdyes").parent().addClass("checked"); }
    else{ $("#cdno").parent().addClass("checked");}
    $("#cddvd").trigger('change');
    }
```

It sets the value in radio buttons, but when i try to access the same value using getValues() : value comes **undefined**

```
function getValues(){
     alert("Power : "+ $('#power').val();) //Power : undefined
     alert("Boot : "+ $('#boot').val();) //Boot : undefiend
    }
```

Why i get this **Power : undefined** value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to select by name, the "#" selector in jQuery selects by ID, this is the quickest form of selector because of this uniquity. You cannot have duplicate IDs, but you can have duplicate names (which is standard radio button group practice).

For your purposes, I'd use a complex selector e.g.

```
$('input[name=boot]:checked').val();
```

Also, your passValues function should use:

```
$("#pyes").prop( "checked", true );
```

This is the recommended way to set a radio button.

Comment: thanx Jeff  for quick reply !! getting value is working by using above suggessted way, but only when i select the radio button. I affraid , passValues() function not setting values properly, though i see the radio is selected after passValues() execution.